# PgBouncer configure auth_user without plain text password

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer, postgresql-14

I am working on configuration of pgBouncer and I was able to make it work with auth_query. Is it possible to somehow encrypt password for auth_user?
Initially I tried to use SCRAM hash but then connections would fail. I've read that md5 is possible, but I have SCAM configured on the server already.

```
;
; pgbouncer configuration example
;
[databases]
test5432 = port=5432 host=localhost auth_user=myauthuser
alin = port=5435 host=localhost auth_user=myauthuser5435
[pgbouncer]
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
admin_users = postgres
;stats_users = monitoring userid
auth_type = scram-sha-256
; put these files somewhere sensible:
auth_query = SELECT usename, passwd FROM user_search($1)
auth_file = users.txt
logfile = pgbouncer.log
pidfile = pgbouncer.pid
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL;
; default values
pool_mode = session
default_pool_size = 20
log_pooler_errors = 1
```

users.txt

```
 "postgres" "SCRAM-SHA-256$4096:Ou4b7GtxwKdQ2NnKwHUxoQ==$RT+nGDekJIzK4L9wxGY4W7$
 "myauthuser" "asdf"
 "myauhuser5345" "asdf"
```

I am trying to run:

```
psql -h 192.168.1.59 -p 6432 -U alinka test5432
```

Comment: Install pgBouncer on the database server machine and use local `trust` authentication for the `auth_user`. If that isn't feasible, use SSL certification authentication.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I removed `myauthuser` from `users.txt` and I added `local  all  myauthuser,postgres  trust` to `pg_hbf.conf`, but now I received an error message in `pgbouncer.log` - `WARNING server login failed: FATAL password authentication failed for user "myauthuser"`.
Postgres is hosted on VM on my laptop and I try to connect from my laptop. Not sure if that makes a difference. Direct connection works using port 5432 works fine.

Comment: Then it is not `local`, and you must not forget a single-host netmask in `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Lets say the plain-text password is `Pk(dw7*ajQ(1xlIv4M.E6sJzI`.  What would you encrypt that to become, and what would be the point of doing so?  Either it possesses something that lets it log in, or it doesn't.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added `host    all             postgres,myauthuser     127.0.0.1/32            trust` to `pg_hba.conf` and now I can login from my laptop to both Postgres intances `5432`  and `5435` through pgbouncer `6432` and switch between them. Thank you!
I think I just don't understand what is connection type `local` doing.

Comment: @jjanes you're right.. I think I got to fixated on this topic.. but on another hand it's also nice not to have to hardcode anything if it ever changes.

Comment: `local` is what is used if you connect over a socket file, rather than an IP address.  so it would be used for `host=/tmp` or `host=/var/run/postgresql`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to encrypt password using scram-sha-256 in my pgbouncer.
When you specify scram-sha-256 in the *config.ini*

```
auth_type = scram-sha-256
```

In your *users.txt* you need to use scram to encrypt the password for your auth_user
e.g.

```
 "myauthuser" "SCRAM-SHA-256$4096:blablabla"
 "myauhuser5345" "SCRAM-SHA-256$4096:blablabla$"
```